# Convert datetime series to numeric timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I know that it's possible to convert a single datetime observation to Unix timestamp by:

```
import datetime as dt
int(dt.datetime.now().timestamp())
```

How could I do this conversion with a Series like this:

```
import pandas as pd
x = dt.datetime.now()
y = x + dt.timedelta(seconds=300)
z = pd.Series([x, y])
```

z:

```
0   2019-03-22 13:53:42.671575
1   2019-03-22 13:58:42.671575
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Use `print (z.astype(np.int64) // 10**9)`

Answer (score 0):

```
z = pd.Series([int(x.timestamp()), int(y.timestamp())])
```

z

```
0    1553259897
1    1553260197
dtype: int64
```

.

```
z = []
for i,s in enumerate(array):
    z[i] = pd.Series([int(s[0].timestamp()), int(s[1].timestamp())])
```

Comment: I have a Series with up to 20,000 time points, is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Sure, make a loop and you will have it:

z = []
For i,s in enumerate(Series):
----z[i] = pd.Series([int(s[0].timestamp()), int(s[1].timestamp())])

Comment: I edited my comment above to show the loop.